# For loop with multiple IF conditions in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to make for loop with the condition over columns in panda DataFrame:

```
import numpy as np  
import pandas as pd


df=pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv("data.csv"))  
print df  

DWWC1980     DWWC1985   DWWC1990  
16.7140310  16.35661439 15.89201716  
20.9414479  18.00822799 15.73516051  
33.95022337 51.87065104 73.76376497  
144.7000805 136.1462017 130.9143924  
54.9506033  75.03339188 93.22994974
```

For loop condition statement:

```
for i in range (1980,2015,5):

    if   any(df["DWWC"+str(i)] <=18.25)  :

            df['MWTP'+str(i)]=(((10-33)/(5))*(df["DWWC"+str(i)]-5))+10  

    elif any((df["DWWC"+str(i)] >  18.25) &  (df["DWWC"+str(i)] <= 36.5)) :

            df['MWTP'+str(i)]=((10/(df.two-df.three))*(df["DWWC"+str(i)]-df.three))+df.Three

    else :
            df['MWTP'+str(i)]=(((df.Three_value-6)/(df.three-5))*(df["DWWC"+str(i)]-6  

df.to_csv('MWTP1.csv',index='ISO3')
```

But When I run this code and compare with manual calculation, I found that only the first condition calculation is correct and didn't go for the other conditions. (df.one, df.two, and df.three are other columns.)

```
  MWTP1980       MWTP1985         MWTP1990  
 25.87096095    30.72758886  37.04060109  
 -77.06996017   20.00112954      95.22533503  
 -290.1012655   -640.6304196    -1068.866556  
 -1845.172654   -1718.865351    -1641.61201  
 -1397.638671   -2171.737373    -2873.130596
```

Comment: So what is the output you are getting vs. the one you would want to get? Please provide complete [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you want to check against all conditions, don't use `elif` and `else`; just use multiple `if`-statements and they will all be checked independently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) and for get columns names `format`:

```
for i in range (1980,2015,5):
    m1 = df["DWWC{}".format(i)] <=18.25
    #inverted m1 mask by ~
    m2 = ~m1 & (df["DWWC{}".format(i)] <= 36.5)
    a = (((10-33)/(5))*(df["DWWC{}".format(i)]-5))+10 
    b = ((10/(df.two-df.three))*(df["DWWC{}".format(i)]-df.three))+df.Three
    c = (((df.Three_value-6)/(df.three-5))*(df["DWWC{}".format(i)]-6

    df["MWTP{}".format(i)] = np.select([m1,m2],[a,b], default=c)
```

Comment: Thank you, but why in the last line you separated just "c"?

Comment: @water77 it is default value, for better readability added to code.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is the usage of `if elif else` as follows:

```py
if any(df["DWWC"+str(i)] <=18.25):
// executes if confidion is true
elif any((df["DWWC"+str(i)] >  18.25) &  (df["DWWC"+str(i)] <= 36.5)):
// executes if first condition is false and second condition is true
else:
// executes if both condition are false
```

So when your first condition is met, it never checks the other ones.
Try changing it to something like that:

```py
if any(df["DWWC"+str(i)] <=18.25):
// executes if first condition is true
if any((df["DWWC"+str(i)] >  18.25) &  (df["DWWC"+str(i)] <= 36.5)):
// executes if second condition is true, regardless of the first
else:
// all other if's are false
```

Comment: Yes, it is one problem, but solution still not working, because always all data should be overwritten.

Comment: @Dor Shinar thank you, Do you think a.any() cause some problems here?

Comment: Yes, you are right @jezrael, now the first condition calculation is wrong due to over writing.

Comment: `any()` is used to test an array of conditions to see if at least one of them is truthy. 
Here though it looks as if you are testing only one condition, so it really doesn't seem necessary. 
One more thing I've noticed is your use of the `&` symbols. The `&` symbols is used for bitwise operations, rather that logical `and` in python (Unlike other languages you may know). If you wanted to make an `and` condition, change it to `if condition1 and condition2:`.